# php/Symfony View Component analog in python/Django

Tags: python, django, symfony1

Symfony has very useful feature - view component, this is small action code and template that you could embed anywhere inside view template:

```
<?php include_component('news') ?>
```

for example in above code mews component executes query in db and display results as block on a site page.

http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#Components

I need something similar for Django to prepare and display login form in each view template.

We can call this a "widget" probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for Django's [template tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) feature.  Template tags can make database calls, render partial templates, or do pretty much anything else you need them to do.  Your example, as a template tag, might look something like this in your templates:

```
{% include_component 'news' %}
```